# Why member variable which is a pointer to another class is allowed to be changed when the object reference is constant?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, operator-overloading, constants

I was reading Effective C++ by Scott Meyers and in Item 11 to describe the gotcha of self assignment writer used the following code

```
class Bitmap { ... };
class Widget {
...
private:
Bitmap *pb; // ptr to a heap-allocated object
};

Widget&
Widget::operator=(const Widget& rhs) // unsafe impl. of operator=
{
delete pb; // stop using current bitmap
pb = new Bitmap(*rhs.pb); // start using a copy of rhs’s bitmap
return *this; // see Item 10
}
```

So when Bitmap pointer of the caller and overloaded parameter reference(rhs) both point to the same memory location rhs gets updated even if it is a const reference in the method. Why does compiler allow it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> both point to the same memory location rhs gets updated even if it is a const reference in the method.

It's only guaranteed that you can't modify the object through the parameter `rhs`. The compiler can't stop you from modifying through other routes. e.g.

```
int a = 0;
const int& ra = a; // a can't be changed via ra
a = 42;            // but the original object is still modifiable
```

Comment: Can you please provide some documentation link that is related to how compiler handles situations like this?

Comment: @FarsanRashid There're not special rules for it. You want some documents demonstrating that the compiler won't check `a = 42` is fine when there's a `const` reference to it?

Comment: That will be helpful I guess.

Comment: @FarsanRashid It's not an easy thing. For example, the above code is well-formed to the standard then the compiler should accept it, but the standard won't state explicitly that the compiler shouldn't perform check for this case.